# PHP MyAdmin problems when opening table

Tags: php, mysql

First of all the mysql is new me so i have no clue how or what to do. I have seen a lot of teaching video about mysql and php. So my problem is that when I log into my phpmyadmin and open a base, called 'Login' and a table called 'users', there is an error message with the following lines: "Some errors have been detected on the server! Please look at the bottom of the window."
So I checked the bottom of the window and there was a huge red warning box with the following lines: There are any idea how to solve this issue? By the way I am using Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon.

```js
Warning in ./libraries/sql.lib.php#613
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Backtrace

./libraries/sql.lib.php#2128: PMA_isRememberSortingOrder(array)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#2079: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'Login',
string 'users',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `users`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
./sql.php#221: PMA_executeQueryAndSendQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'Login',
string 'users',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `users`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
```

Comment: If you haven't written any code on your own, this is not a programming question. This looks like you are using a pretty current PHP version with an older version of phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all get backup sql.lib.php before editing.

```
sudo cp /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php.backup
```

Or you can do it manually without command line. Got to `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries` folder directory and search it and copy past `sql.lib.php` and rename `sql.lib.php.backup`

After do this

```
sudo nano /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php
```

Press CTRL + W and find this code `(count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']  == 1)` and replace it with `((count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1)` after `sudo service apache2 restart`. Here mistake first braket ().

Answer (score 0):

From that I remember it is know issue, that could happen if you have old version of phpmyadmin and some newest version of php.
Is it  your server and you have root rights? If yes, you can update versions or just provide some small fixes to phpmyadmin code.
If it's not your server, ask support to update versions or fix that error manually.

Comment: Can I update the phpmyadmin in the page for example the settings menu or other?
Or I have to update them using the terminal?

Comment: I don't know is it possible to update it from few clicks in phpmyadmin. I know only one way - using command line and file manager. I think you can search manuals on Google. Create backups and try to update. Or just fix it in phpmyadmin code (there is manuals how and that you will need to change).